# Mark third-party spawned threads for further killing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

In our app we have an external library we use to work over DAL. Sometimes it hanging out on some trivial methods like opening database connection. It just spawn another one thread for connecting and this thread is never termintated.

So, how can I make some mark in thread being spawned?
I could then iterate over app's thread list, find these dead threads and just kill them.

Answer (score 0):

You fundamentally cannot do this. If you need this behavior, you should be using processes, not threads.

The textbook answer is this: With the cooperation of the code those threads run, you can do this anyway you want. Without their cooperation, this will never be safe or reliable.

Either fix the library or isolate the library from your code by wrapping the library in a service process. If a thread malfunctions or gets stuck, its process context is contaminated.